# automate file transfer to Azure VM (windows server) using tfs builds

Tags: azure, .net-core, tfsbuild, build-automation, azure-virtual-machine

We are using .NetCore in one project of our solutions.

I am trying to automate the build output of DotNet application and publish files to an Azure VM hosting this application.

I have tried many solutions but none worked.

what is the best way to upload files from a local server to an azure VM using TFS builds for a DotNet(1.1.0) project.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to define a CI build for .net-core project. If you are using *TFS2017 update2* and later you could directly select the **ASP.NET Core** template, you could refer this tutorial: [Build your ASP.NET Core app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-core?tabs=vsts)

Otherwise you need to use manually select related build task  such as use command line call dotnet restore, dotnet publish. You could take a look at this link: [How to build and deploy ASP.NET Core app to Azure](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/support/build-deploy-asp-net-core-app-azure/)

If you simply want to copy/upload files  to an Azure VM, you could use [**Azure File Copy**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/deploy/azure-file-copy)  task. This task is used to copy application files and other artifacts that are required in order to install the app; such as PowerShell scripts, PowerShell-DSC modules, and more to Microsoft Azure storage blobs or virtual machines (VMs).

Comment: Thanks @patrik-MSFT. I tried the Azure File Copy with all its configurations, I am getting an error on 'select-AzureRmSubscription', which if I run on the build server also does not exist (which is the error in the build output). they say it exists in the Azure powershell module but when I list the Azure command the above is not between them. I am frustrated with it now :(

Comment: @JohnnyZghaib AzureRmSubscription is required if you select **Azure Resource Manager** for the Azure Connection Type parameter. You need to create/conifgure an Azure Resource Manager service endpoint for the subscription in your TFS service endpoint. See Azure Resource Manager overview for more details: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/resource-group-overview/  Did you miss this setting?